# how would i get the average of a previous date and update it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to write a query that will have the average(that wont be hard) but when I get that average I want to save it somewhere. Let's I have a average save from last month table_a.last_month_average. And now I run the query again and this would be the current_month_average. I want to compare this two columns and see if the current_month_average increase from last_month_average.

After I compare I would like to output the biggest average number from those two. After I do this I would like to move the current_month_average to last_month_average so that one becomes the old average when next month the query runs.

Is this possible in sql? or maybe there is a better way to do this?any suggestions will help.

Comment: right now i only have it to get the average ,not sure how to even start the other part with comparing the two month. The old month average will already be in the database.

Comment: You can use avg(columnname) as avg is a buildin function. Please provide the query so that we can help you?  http://www.sqlteachers.com

Answer (score 0):

> After I compare I would like to output the biggest average number from those two. After I do this I would like to move the current_month_average to last_month_average so that one becomes the old average when next month the query runs.

By my understanding, this operation is to select maximum month_average from all history records. So you don't need to keep a record of current_month_average and last_month_average. Instead, a table of all history month average is helpful. Assume there is table named **monthaverage** with columns (Id, Month, Average), you can query

```
SELECT TOP 1 T1.*
    , CASE WHEN 
        T1.Average > (SELECT TOP 1 T2.Average 
                      FROM monthaverage T2
                      WHERE T2.Month < T1.Month 
                      ORDER BY Month DESC) 
      THEN 'Increased' 
      ELSE 'Not Increased' 
      END
FROM monthaverage T1
ORDER BY T1.Average DESC
```

If you have chance to run it from SQL SERVER 2012, you can leverage LAST_VALUE function. Query is like

```
SELECT TOP 1 *, CASE WHEN Average > LAST_VALUE(Average) OVER (ORDER BY Month) THEN 'Increased' ELSE 'Not Increased' END
FROM monthaverage
ORDER BY Average DESC
```